# Desktop sharing Ubuntu 21.04 - same network

Tags: 21.04, video-streaming, desktop-sharing

How can I share my desktop's monitor to another laptop on the same network? (For watching video stream.)  There used to be a thing called "desktop sharing" but it isn't coming up in my system.

Comment: Do you want to broadcast from one computer to another? Or is your goal to have one computer control another desktop? 

Comment: Broadcast. I just want to have the same thing playing on both in sync, basically, as I walk room to room.